# Katalon Studio - Asking for user input to select link

Tags: input, groovy, katalon-studio

I am currently automating testing for a ticketing system application in Katalon Studio.

The problem is: when a new ticket has been created (the test automates this beforehand), a ticket name is automatically assigned to it (e.g. 'PML-0121') and this is shown at the top of a table. What I want the code below to do is to ask the user to input the ticket name, then the test will find the link with the corresponding name and navigate to the link.

Could anyone tell me what other operators I need to be using, or if there is even possible code for this issue?

Here is the script:

```
'Click on ticket link'
JFrame frame = new JFrame('User Input Frame')

frame.requestFocus()

String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, 'Enter ticket name:')

'Select userInput option'
WebUI.click(findTestObject(String userInput))

'Reach Out button'
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Tickets - Tickets (new)/a_PML-0118 - Emai/a_Reach Out'))
```

Comment: Share table html if you still need the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If the new ticket name is always on top of the table, could you get it automatically instead of asking the tester input the value?

Comment: I have thought about this before however I am unsure on how to get Katalon to always select the top link on the table.

Comment: I think the top link's index will be different from the other links. If you inspect the xpath, you may find out that top link will have index 0 or 1 (you could double check). For example: in the top link locator: xpath = //td[0]/a